# Pepper Robot Tablet: Cannot show the specific webpage on Pepper Tablet

Tags: tablet, pepper

I came across an issue is I noticed not all website link can be shown on the Pepper Tablet, is that right? for example, I want to show this link: "https://rt-webchatapp-v5.netlify.app/" which I developed for users to register, but on the tablet, it is always white screen. Can anyone explain it? how can I show above link on Pepper Tablet?

This website is I developed for my research, I have been used for at least 6 months, I am hoping I can use on Pepper robot directly.

Comment: Can you show your piece of code(WebView part)?

Comment: @androider The web application I used Reactjs + nodejs

Comment: I can confirm this behavior (independent on the question author, just run `qicli call ALTabletService.showWebview "https://rt-webchatapp-v5.netlify.app/"
`). However, I assume, this is not Pepper related, but influenced by the old Android on the Pepper's tablet.

Comment: The webview there is pretty old and might not support something from your page, but I'm not sure how to collect the error. Can you find `adb` on the robot? If yes try running `adb logcat` to collect all the logs, and try again and look for errors.

Comment: It could be due to pepper running an old browser version, for example the browser of the pepper im working with uses javascript 1.7.  If the webpage you want to display uses any new javascript features, pepper won't be able to display it.

Comment: I think so, thank you everyone to answer my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The webview on Pepper's tablet is old. It uses Javascript 1.7 and might not support newest javascript features.